# ¿cómo cerrar JFrame desde un JPanel que se encuentra dentro de este?

Tags: java, jframe

Tengo un JFrame que dentro tiene un JPanel con un botón. Lo que quiero es que con este botón se cierre el JFrame y se habra otra ventana. El punto es ¿Cómo lo cierro con el botón desde el JPanel?

Comment: ¿El `JFrame` y el `JPanel` se encuentran en clases y archivos diferentes?

Comment: Sí ambos están separados. Pero el JFrame llama al JPanel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalmente, la respuesta de Yo Albert funcionaría si el `JFrame` y el `JPanel` se encuentran en el mismo archivo `.java`. Pero en el caso de que se encuentren separados podrías intentar utilizando esta línea en el lugar donde quieres cerrar el `JFrame`:

```
JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
frame.dispose();
```

Esto te permite obtener el `JFrame` para realizar otras acciones si asi lo deseas, pero en este caso concreto podrías hacerlo rápidamente así:

`((JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this)).dispose();`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes agregar un evento `clicked`al boton y utilizar los siguientes metodos;

```
// Al pulsar el boton de la opcion "asignado al evento" abrira la ventana deseada
   Jframe_nuevo J_nuevo = new Jframe_nuevo();
    J_nuevo.setVisible(true); //Hace la ventana visible
    this.dispose(); //Para que cierre la ventana anterior
```

Answer (score 0):

no se si llego tarde pero te mando la respuesta o al menos como lo hago yo. Un poco de explicacion. Para cerrar el JFrame el evento tiene que estar dentro del JFrame y despues lo envias a todas las clases que quieras para que lo cierre.

Esta es la clase del JFrame

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Ventana extends JFrame{

    public Ventana() {

        setBounds(200,200,500,300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Cerrando desde otra clase");

        add(new Panel(new eventoCerrar()));
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class eventoCerrar implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

y aqui tenemos la clase JPanel:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Panel extends JPanel{

    public Panel(ActionListener aL ) {

        JButton cerrar = new JButton("Cerrar");
        cerrar.addActionListener(aL);

        add(cerrar);
    }

}
```

Como puedes ver, el evento esta dentro del JFrame y lo pasamos por parametro a la clase JPanel y desde ahi le agregamos la accion al boton.

Un saludo